# Images within noscript

Tags: seo, images, noscript

> **Note:** My question is not about JavaScript
>
> **Note:** My question is how to make the HTML accessible to search engines.
>
> **Note:** My question is not about hiding texts, is on block loading of images in order to use LazyLoad.
> **Note:** Library used in tests: https://github.com/brcontainer/smooth-images-js

I tested various techniques of blocking the loading of images to use `effect LazyLoad` (I'm developing in JavaScript), was the only efficient `<noscript>`:

The `HTML structure` that would, with `LazyLoad loading` of images is achieved via the `viewport` (visible part of web page).

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <span class="lazyload">
                <noscript><img src="foto-m0101.jpg" alt="image description"></noscript>
        </span>
        consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <span class="lazyload">
                <noscript><img src="foto-m0201.jpg" alt="image description"></noscript>
        </span>
        consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <span class="lazyload">
                <noscript><img src="foto-m0301.jpg" alt="image description"></noscript>
        </span>
        consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
```

When `<noscript>` with the image is the `view-port` (visible part of web page).

- The jquery-plugin gets the DOM: `$("span.lazyload")`.
- The jquery-plugin checks if the `<noscript> <img>` is on view-port.
- The jquery-plugin to create a `new Image` with `Image.onload = function(){}`.
- When the image loaded `Image.onload` will insert `<img>` outside the `<noscript>`.

For clarity. Suppose that only the first `<noscript>` is the view-port (`<noscript><img src="foto-m0101.jpg" alt="image description"></noscript>`).
After the onload JavaScript will do the HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <span class="lazyload">
                <img src="foto-m0101.jpg" alt="image description">
                <noscript><img src="foto-m0101.jpg" alt="image description"></noscript>
        </span>
        consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <span class="lazyload">
                <noscript><img src="foto-m0201.jpg" alt="image description"></noscript>
        </span>
        consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <span class="lazyload">
                <noscript><img src="foto-m0301.jpg" alt="image description"></noscript>
        </span>
        consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
```

---

[edit]
I believe that Google displays the DOM also modified by JavaScript.
Look I used the tool *Fetch as Google*.

**Look at the results:**

> Without my jquery-plugin and `<noscript>` (i.e. pure HTML):
>
> [image: http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2632/webpagethumbnail1.jpg]

---

> With jquery-plugin and `<noscript>`:
>
> [image: http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/3485/webpagethumbnail.jpg]
>
> **Note:** The JavaScript that showcased images and manipulated the DOM.

**Question:**

- This is a bad practice for search engines (I refer to HTML)?
- If it is a bad practice, you could put an example of good practice?
- If there is another question talking about `<noscript>` with "IMAGES", forgive me.
- If the JavaScript displays images and *Fetch as Google* displays the content normally (like the browser) so Google indexes the DOM manipulated by JavaScript?

> **Note:** I did not find any doubts about `<noscript>` with images.

Comment: As the page scrolls, do you manipulate the `noscript` element in the DOM in order to show the image?

Comment: When scrolling the page which is in the `view-port` will be loaded using `javascript-dom`. I'll take the elements noscript / img that are in `view-port` and will get the `SRC=""` attribute, I will remove the `noscript` with javascript and instead will only get the IMG (when the image is loaded).

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at this question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165643/load-html-then-load-images-using-ajax-in-jquery it has an AJAX lazy load answer and jsfiddle. I would try and avoid using `<noscript>`

Comment: The **SRC attribute** empty is bad. I need something that does not disturb the indexing of images. My question is about `indexing images` in `search engines`. It's like I said: `My question is not about javascript`. Edit your answer please. Thanks.

Comment: Have you created and submitted an XML Image sitemap?

Comment: The problem is that maintaining the Sitemap,
HTML pages would have to have maintenance manual. Not the best practice at the time.

Comment: Are you using a CMS?

Comment: I have several websites, made ​​with php, html, asp-classic, .net (c#).

I do not use CMS,
I develop from scratch.

Comment: Well in that case I would develop an image sitemap script from scratch. Have you not considered working with WordPress which is possibly the most popular CMS in the world and can do just about anything?

Comment: I prefer to create from scratch. Moreover as I was told on several sites have different programming languages​​, besides pure html. I really want a `HTML structure` to index images. thanks.